# Many items in one table cell

Tags: views, 8

I have a very complicated view, and I can't change the existing field structure (it's an established and functioning site). This is a simplification of the problem, but it has to happen this way, I can't turn it the other way around...

There are two node types (Author and Book), the Book type has an entity reference pointing at the Author.

The view I want to create lists the authors and needs to display all the Book titles in a single column (one author per row, all the book titles in one cell together).

How do I create the entry in the view, so it does that?

Comment: Any luck? Did you try the Views Aggregator Plus module?

Comment: I went a different route in the end. I did know about that module and I'd rejected it previously for a different project because doesn't use any D8 capabilities. It's perfect for plugins ... doesn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the result you want using the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) contrib module.

It's still in alpha for Drupal 8, but it allows you to group and aggregate results.